# Zotac motherboard beeps four (4) times, medium-length, on startup

Tags: motherboard

When turning on new computer the motherboard speaker beeps 4 times, then restarts the computer, when it beeps 4 times again and outputs nothing to the display.

The motherboard error display also shows Fifty five (55), but I cannot locate any references to the error codes Zotac uses.

Thinking this might be the "system timer error" I replaced the CMOS battery (though motherboard is new) and no joy.

The model in question is Z77ITX-A-E but may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a very stiff RAM slot, which locked down even though the RAM was not fully seated, removing all the components and replacing them one by one showed my error.

Comment: Heh. Looks like the first beep was a long one. I feel for you on spending effort for a silly error. With my stepfather, we put together and apart my new computer like 5 or 6 times, desperately looking for the issue as to why it didn't turn on. Turns out he had accidentally put the power supply on 240V instead of 120. xD

Comment: Ey! I'm having just the same problem with a Zotac Mini PC, some help?

Comment: Did you try pushing hard on the RAM? How many beeps? The manual has list of beeps and meanings

Comment: Push on RAM to secure it, don't flip up the tabs... If your issue is resolved, please accept this answer to remove it from the "unanswered" pile.